# Automatic voltage matching circuit

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I need a circuit that automatically adjusts and provides the same voltage read from a reference point.

For example, the circuit gets 3v from the reference, it starts to provide 3v. It senses 2.85, it starts to provide 2.85.

The target voltage range is between 2v and 3v. Ideally, I'd love to find an IC that already does this. Accuracy is quite important, however, providing say 10mV under the reference voltage is also very acceptable.

Max needed is 300mA.

Could anybody help please? I have searched everywhere and can't find anything and of course, I could try and design the circuit, but I'm after something clever that other's have already figured out how to do rather than re-invent the wheel (if possible).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a very common circuit called a *unity gain buffer*. It can be made with a single op-amp.

Comment: Oh that sounds like great news, I'm going to search for that now - thank you!

Comment: @RickPerrion Keep in mind that you want \$300\:\text{mA}\$. The output of unity gain buffers often won't meet this current compliance. But, as an example that does, look at the [LMH6321](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6321.pdf?ts=1645595628831&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

Comment: @ThePhoton, please can you expand your comment into an Answer (before someone else comes along and posts the same thing your wrote).

Comment: There are *tracking* LDOs made exactly for that purpose. Most of these are made by TI but I guess other make them too.

Comment: All of you have greatly contributed toward finding the right solution, but I do think that Lorenzo's suggestion of tracking LDO's is what lead me to the best solution and that is to use an adjustable LDO to do the trick, where the ADJ pin will get the reference voltage. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an amplifier with a voltage gain of 1 (a.k.a. unity gain) and low enough output impedance to supply 300mA to your load. You need to know what the load is to calculate how low that output impedance should be.

A unity gain amp is not hard. The simplest form uses a single op amp stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGyWuJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and this can be realised with any general purpose op amp. However most of these will not supply 300mA (highest is typically 10-20mA for something like the venerable 5532), so you need to dig a little deeper. You have two options:

1. look for a [power op amp](https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/op-amps/power/overview.html). These exist, typically in similar packages to power transistors. This might be your simplest option.
2. Take a low current unity gain buffer and add transistors at the output to boost the output current. This is a technique widely used in audio power amp designs, for instance, where maximum current would be in amps not mA. To do it for 300mA is not so hard, but you need to understand amplifiers and how they work. [This page](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/op-amp-cookbook-part-2) has a good primer, including a useful section on current boosting, to get you started.

Comment: search for opamp current booster there are entire application notes devoted to that

Answer (score 0):

> *I need a circuit that automatically adjusts and provides the same
> voltage read from a reference point. For example, the circuit gets 3v
> from the reference, it starts to provide 3v. It senses 2.85, it starts
> to provide 2.85.*

A simple wire link should do what you want; it ensures the output voltage equals the input voltage. It will also have exceptional high frequency performance compared to an op-amp buffer.

> *I'm after something clever*

That may be a weakness in your motivation because quite often, the simplest solutions are the best.

Comment: Only if the source can supply 300mA. Presumably the OP has some reason to want to buffer the source.

Comment: The requirements of the load vary between 40mA to spikes of 300mA, so it's a maximum of 300mA needed, thank you for your answers gents!